# How to add a local JNI jar in a pom file properly?

Tags: java, maven, java-native-interface

I have a SpringbootApplication that provides a REST API, let's call it `fetchPrediction`.

This `fetchPrediction` API uses some classes defined inside a JAR file, which is a JNI.

My application compiles and starts, however, if I call the `fetchPrediction` API it fails.

When I do jar -xvf on the created jar after `mvn clean install`, I do not see the classes that should be picked up by including the jar dependency.

Also, when I try to run the Jar file I see `ClassNotDefinedException` for the classes inside the JAR.

How can I do this properly?

Currently I am importing the JAR dependency as follows:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jarcom.jarlib</groupId>
        <artifactId>jarname</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/jarname.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Have you taken a look into the jar which created by the spring-boot-maven-plugin ? This is usually larger than the usual jar file?

Comment: yes. those files are not there.

Comment: BTW: I would suggest to start using a repository manager and deploy the jar into the repository manager and than you change back to usual dependencies. No need for system scope (which is deprecated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an spring boot application you usually do not have JNI parts. Furthermore the [spring-boot-maven-plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/usage.html) by default does not include dependencies with `<scope>system</scope>` that's the reason why you do not see the jar file in the resulting jar.

You have to have to configure the spring-boot-maven-plugin and set the includeSystemScope to `true` as [described in the docs for the plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html#includeSystemScope).

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>repackage</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        ...
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: Mah MAN, you saved the day. Much appreciated. Wow. The googling I did for this ....Thanks so much